# add the authentication procedure and security to android app. - Android

Tags: android, security

I need to increase the security of my android app. Actually my android app. will not be for Google play Store (which provides some licensing options to protect your app.) it will be used for some local companies that used the same app (Desktop  app). However, I want to support two versions for my app.  which are:

- **Demo version**: for testing aims (after the given period end, the app will stopped!)
- **Actual version**: this if the user want to pay for the app.

**What I need:**

- To increase the security of my app. from installing it another time or on another device for the same user!
- For my code I used ProGuard which is a tool provided by Android that lets you obfuscate (make harder to read) your code during packaging. cause there are many reverse-engineering application that used for unpacking the compiled code and viewing the source code (actually I tried some of them and its really amazing to restore the sourse code from .apk!) ..
- I think to use the MAC address of each device the app. installed on and then store it into internal database and generate a number form it (in somehow), then ask user enters it (which I the one who knows this number and provider for it) if it is true, the app run  else not. But, it's just idea I do not know how this can happen or even from where I can start or even also if that will help!
- I tried also SharedPreferences But this does not help!
- Actually I do not need for external database on server to read the username or the password for eligible users for app. I need to do that by my app. itself!

**In sum please,**

How can I protect my app from installing many times for same user or continuing using after testing period ends, etc. (I mean make it more secure)!

any ideas, any suggestions, any useful examples or sites are also desirable.

Sorry for this long question,

Comment: A couple of things.

1)Phone's don't have a MAC address unless they're on wifi.  And MAC addresses can't be trusted anyway, they can be changed.

2)There is no way to really secure an app without hitting a server.  Any method you use can be trivially broken.  If you don't physically control the hardware, you can't trust the app.  All you can do is increase the time it takes to hack it from a few hours to a day or so.  IMO not even worth it.  To be secure, you have to have data that the app needs live on your hardware and have your server be the one to decide if they're authenticated or not.

Comment: mmm yes, unfortunately I noticed that when I read many references and tried many ways, and now after your note I make sure from that. furthermore, hitting the sever is another story, which I don't have any idea about how can this done! cause my app. will be used for external services for company!  anyway thanks Mr. @GabeSechan ...